# Page layout not available in one of the subsite

Tags: 2013, site-collection, page-layout, sub-site

I have a site collection with many sub sites.

I have created several page layouts at top level which are all available in all sub sites except one.  That page layout is published.

In all other sub sites, I can go and apply that page layout on any page. But in that specific sub site, that page layout is not available in ribbon when you go in Edit mode of a page.

How to fix this?

Comment: What about the other pagelayouts, are they available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In site settings there is a section to select what page layouts are available on that site.  You can set this to inherit or choose specific page layouts.  That would be the first place to check.

Answer (score 0):

Just activate **SharePoint Server Publishing** ([at here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-publishing-features-479677a6-8b33-4ac7-907d-071c1c7e4518)) and you'll be able to get done.

This will create a folder called "Pages" in the content of your site. Make sure you do not already have it. In this case, remove that before activating the feature.